# Prove that if a linear map $f$ is an endomorphism it can be expressed as the difference of two automorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

The statement I wan't to prove is that if I have a linear map $f:E \rightarrow E$, where E is a vector space of finite dimension, I can express it as the difference of two automorphisms $g$ and $h$, $f =  g - h$.

Suppose we have f defined in a base $u_1, ..., u_n$, I need to find two bases of $E$ $v_1, ..., v_n$ and $w_1, ...,w_n$, such that $f(u_i) = v_i - w_i$. This way, if I define $g(u_i) = v_i$ and $h(u_i) = w_i$ I will have $f = g - h$.

So this amounts to finding a base $w_1, ...,w_n$ such that $f(u_1) + w_1, ...,f(u_n) + w_n$ is a base, because the two bases I described above would be $\{v_i = f(u_i) + w_i\}$, and $\{w_i\}$.

$\{f(u_i) + w_i\}$ is a base iff they are linearly independent. So if we have $0 = \sum a_i (f(u_i) + w_i) = f(\sum a_i u_i) + \sum a_i w_i$. From here $f(\sum a_i u_i) = -\sum a_i w_i$, but I can't find a sufficient condition wrt $w_i$ such that $a_i = 0$. Any suggestions?

Is there an alternative approach to this proof?

Comment: If $E$ is a vector space over an infinite field, taking $h$ to be $-\lambda \text{id}$ for $\lambda$ not an eigenvalue of $f$, and $g = f + h$ will do the trick. Over smaller fields you will have to be more careful, and over more general rings even more so

Comment: I forgot to mention that $E$ is a vector space of finite dimension, I have edited the question.